# Memory leak with string related function in c++

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

The following function causes a memory leak in my code. could you please help guys, when it was going wrong? I think there should be no leak when we are using strings as STL will take care about the memory heap allocation and reallocation.Please give me some hunch for the reasons

```
int CProcessMgr::readField(std::string currlocline)
{   
    //std::string currlocline = currline;
    if((currlocline.find('[') != -1) && (currlocline.find(']') != -1))
    {
        currlocline.erase(std::remove(currlocline.begin(), currlocline.end(), '['),       currlocline.end());
        currlocline.erase(std::remove(currlocline.begin(), currlocline.end(), ']'), currlocline.end());
        size_t loc = currlocline.find(" ");     
        m_inpData.updateDate = currlocline.substr(0, loc);
        m_inpData.updateTime = currlocline.substr(loc+1);
        //GetTimeValues(currlocline.c_str());
    }
    else if(currlocline.find(SYMBOL_ROW) != -1)
    {
        size_t size = currlocline.find(":");
        if(size != -1)
        {
            string currticker = currlocline.substr(size+1);
            size = currticker.find("bk.HKd");
            if(size != -1)
            {
                m_inpData.ticker = currticker.substr(0, size);
                m_inpData.ticker.append(".HK");
            }
            else 
                m_inpData.ticker = currticker;
        }       
    }           
    else if(currlocline.find(TOTAL_VOL) != -1)
    {
        //update previous record info and store it into the map.
        size_t size = currlocline.find(":");
        m_inpData.totalVolume = atol(currlocline.substr(size+1).c_str());
    }
    else if(currlocline.find(BID_ROW) != -1)
    {
        //update previous record info and store it into the map.
        size_t size = currlocline.find(":");
        m_inpData.bidPrice = atof(currlocline.substr(size+1).c_str());
    }
    else if(currlocline.find(BID_SIZE) != -1)
    {
        //update previous record info and store it into the map.
        size_t size = currlocline.find(":");
        m_inpData.bidsize = atoi(currlocline.substr(size+1).c_str());
    }
    else if(currlocline.find(ASK_ROW) != -1)
    {
        //update previous record info and store it into the map.
        size_t size = currlocline.find(":");
        m_inpData.askPrice = atof(currlocline.substr(size+1).c_str());
    }
    else if(currlocline.find(ASK_SIZE) != -1)
    {
        //update previous record info and store it into the map.
        size_t size = currlocline.find(":");
        m_inpData.asksize = atoi(currlocline.substr(size+1).c_str());
    }
    else if(currlocline.find(ROW80_3_TEXT) != -1)
    {
        //update previous record info and store it into the map.
        size_t size = currlocline.find(":");
        m_inpData.row_3 = currlocline.substr(size+1).c_str();
    }
    else if(currlocline.find(ROW80_4_TEXT) != -1)
    {
        //update previous record info and store it into the map.
        size_t size = currlocline.find(":");
        m_inpData.row_4 = currlocline.substr(size+1).c_str();
    }
    else if(currlocline.find(ROW80_5_TEXT) != -1)
    {
        //update previous record info and store it into the map.
        size_t size = currlocline.find(":");
        m_inpData.row_5 = currlocline.substr(size+1).c_str();
    }
    else if(currlocline.find(ROW80_6_TEXT) != -1)
    {
        //update previous record info and store it into the map.
        size_t size = currlocline.find(":");
        m_inpData.row_6 = currlocline.substr(size+1).c_str();
    }
    else if(currlocline.find(ROW80_7_TEXT) != -1)
    {
        //update previous record info and store it into the map.
        size_t size = currlocline.find(":");
        m_inpData.row_7 = currlocline.substr(size+1).c_str();
    }
    else if(currlocline.find(ROW80_8_TEXT) != -1)
    {
        //update previous record info and store it into the map.
        size_t size = currlocline.find(":");
        m_inpData.row_8 = currlocline.substr(size+1).c_str();
    }
    else if(currlocline.find(ROW80_9_TEXT) != -1)
    {
        //update previous record info and store it into the map.
        size_t size = currlocline.find(":");
        m_inpData.row_9 = currlocline.substr(size+1).c_str();
    }
    else if(currlocline.find(ROW80_10_TEXT) != -1)
    {
        //update previous record info and store it into the map.
        size_t size = currlocline.find(":");
        m_inpData.row_10 = currlocline.substr(size+1).c_str();
    }
    else if(currlocline.find(ROW80_11_TEXT) != -1)
    {
        //update previous record info and store it into the map.
        size_t size = currlocline.find(":");
        m_inpData.row_11 = currlocline.substr(size+1).c_str();
    }
    else if(currlocline.find(ROW80_12_TEXT) != -1)
    {
        //update previous record info and store it into the map.
        size_t size = currlocline.find(":");
        m_inpData.row_12 = currlocline.substr(size+1).c_str();
    }
    else if(currlocline.find(ROW80_13_TEXT) != -1)
    {
        //update previous record info and store it into the map.
        size_t size = currlocline.find(":");
        m_inpData.row_13 = currlocline.substr(size+1).c_str();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What evidence do you have that it is leaking memory?

Comment: Can't see any obvious memory leaks but your calls to `c_str()` on temporary strings and storing the results in something that obviously outlives the function (`m_inpData`) are very very suspect and must be causing trouble (crashes, UB, you name it)

Comment: Memory consumption of application is growing drastically when i am using this function. I try to debug memory leak with VLD, they say that there is memory leak(of 16 bytes) for each string assignment in this function.

Comment: one thing i need to mention is that m_inpData in this problem is a global structure

Comment: What's the type of `m_inpData.row_12`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i resolved this issue, thanks for your response till now.

Issue is with memset of the structure. Because of this memset, they creating memory every time i am visiting to this code block. I am removing that statement, it looks fine